# Error url parameter when save form element in zend framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-route

In `module.config.php`

```
...
'may_terminate' => true,
'child_routes' => array(
   'resetpassword' => array(
      'type' => 'Literal',
      'options' => array(
         'route' => '/reset-password',
         'defaults' => array(
            'controller' => 'User\Controller\Index',
            'action' => 'resetpassword',
          ),
       ),
    ),
)
...
```

And form reset password .phtml

```
<?php
    $user_id = 1;
    $token = 'ABCXYZ'
    $form = $this->form;
    $form->prepare();
    $form->setAttribute('action', $this->url('user/resetpassword?user_id='.$user_id.'&token='.$token));
    $form->setAttribute('id', 'reset-password-form');
?>
```

If I set `$form->setAttribute('action', $this->url('user/resetpassword'));` is OK, but when set params is user_id with token => Error
How to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Because the first argument of Url view helper is route name. If you want add some query params, you can use third argument (`$options` - [see documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.view.helpers.url.html#query-string-arguments))

Example:

```
$url = $this->url('user/resetpassword', [], ['query' => ['user_id' => $user_id]]);
```